# NameError: name 'lсon' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import math
lcon = float(input('Введи длину конуса (метров): '))
un1 = int(input('Введи угол наклона (градусов): '))
un = round((un1/2),1)
rcil = float(input('Введи радиус цилиндра (метров): '))
hcil = float(input('Введи высоту цилиндра (метров): '))
zap = int(input('На сколько заполнена цилиндрическая ёмкость (процентов): '))
proz = float(input('Производительность насоса (тонн в час): '))
plot = float(input('Какова плотность продукта (килограмм/дицеметр^3): '))
print ('Найдём объём конуса.')
rkon = round((lcon * math.sin(un)),1)
print (rkon,' - радиус конуса в метрах.')
hkon = round((lсon * math.cos(un)),1)
print (hkon,' - высота конуса в метрах.')
vkon = round(((3,14 * rkon**2 * hkon)/3),1)
print (vkon,' - радиус конуса в метрах^3.')
zapvkon = proz*vkon
print (zapvkon,' - объём заполненной конической ёмкости.')
print ('Теперь , найдём высоту столба жидкости для конуса.')
print ('Чтобы найти hk , найдём высоту незаполненной части конуса :')
vkpol = round((vkon - zapvkon),1)
hp = rcon * math.ctg(un)
rkons = (3**((3*vkon)/(3,14*math.ctg(un))))
hpolkon = rkons * math.ctg(un)
hkos = hkon - hpolkon
print (hkos, ' - Высота столба жидкости (в метрах).')
print ('Найдём объём цилиндра.')
vcil = round((3,14 * rcil**2 * hcil),1)
print (vcil , ' - объём полного цилиндра (в метрах^3).')
vzapcil = zapvkon
print (vzapcill ,'- объм заполненного цилиндра (в метрах^3).')
print ('Найдём высоту столба жидкости для цилиндра.')
hcilr = vzapcill/(3,14*rcil**2)
print (hcilr , ' - это высота столба жидкости для цилиндра (в метрах).')
print ('Найдём , за какое время можно перекачать жидкость.')
proz1 = round((proz/3),1)
print ('Найдём массу жидкости')
mjid = plot * vzapcill
t = round((mjid/proz1),2)
print (t , ' - время за которое перекачается жидкость (в СЕКУНДАХ).')
```

Написал калькулятор, пишет что нету переменной lcon. 
В ЧЁМ ОШИБКА ?

Answer (score 3):

В 13 строке в переменной "lcon" у вас буква "с" набрана в русской раскладке. Замените её на английскую и будет вам счастье.

UPD: В числе 3.14 в качестве разделителя дробной части нужно использовать точку, а не запятую.